# cmd arguments into char** in c

Tags: c, string, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to do the following:

given a program with cmd arguments, I'm trying to store certain strings from `argv` into a `char**`, but I'm new to C and I'm really uncertain how to do so and keep getting segmentation fault. How do I do so?

**Example:** 

The program Run Executing the line  "Program arg2 arg3 arg5 "

Now I want to save `arg2` and `arg5` into a new String array, lets call it 
`StringFromArgs` , and its a `char**`,

I can also tell that `argv[1]` and `argv[3]` are the ones I need,
And lets say I know the max capacity of `StringsFromArgs` is 3.

**How do I write:**

```
StringsFromArgs[0]=argv[1]
StringsFromArgs[1]=argv[2]
StringFromArgs[2]=NULL
```

*edit*
**sample code**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
char** stringsFromArgs;
stringsFromArgs = malloc( 3 * sizeof(char*) ) ;
int i;int k=0;
for(i=1; i<argc; i++){
   if(argv[i]= somecondition){
      stringsFromArgs[k] = argv[i];
      k++;
   }
}
//do something
return 0;
}
```

****edit:**
ended up solving it using your answers, thanks!

Comment: Did you malloc space for StringsFromArgs?

Comment: I have, It still won't work for some reason...

Comment: Most probably, you are not malloc'ing the StringsFromArgs correctly. Give us the malloc code and we will be able to point out the error.

Comment: Can't see any mistake there except "if(argv[i]= somecondition)" where it should be "if(argv[i] == somecondition)"

Comment: Also, as "argv[i]" is a string, you can't just do a " == " comparison only if you know, what you are doing. I would say, you have to do a "strcmp".

Comment: @Tai look my edited answer.

Comment: @Tai: If you compare `argv[i] == somecondition` then you're comparing pointers, not the content of strings. I assume you want to check if the string matches some other string?  Then you need to do more work (see [strcmp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncmp)) or write your own string match function.

Comment: @Tai: Other issue with your code, you don't compare the result of [malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) against NULL, and you don't [free](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) the allocated `StringsFromArgs` either. Plus, there's a typo where `stringsFromArgs` is lowercase, i.e. different variable name than declared. Please fix your code, make sure it compiles, then post the corrected version.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is::

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
 char** StringsFromArgs ;

 StringsFromArgs = malloc( 3 * sizeof(char*) ) ;
 if( StringsFromArgs == NULL ) 
 {
  return -1 ; // ERROR allocating memory
 }

 StringsFromArgs[0]=argv[1] ;
 StringsFromArgs[1]=argv[3] ;
 StringFromArgs[2]=NULL ;

 free( StringsFromArgs ) ;
 return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: why the free command came there ?? it will confuse the user if the intension is to show that at the end you have to free the memory

Comment: Ofcourse, the intention is to show the usage of malloc and that at the end, you DO HAVE TO FREE THE MEMORY.

Comment: problem is I don't know in advance which argv[i] I want. I'm finding them during a loop

Comment: @Tai you can loop it by `argc`.

Comment: I'm doing so, but then it won't work with the StringsFromArgs[0]=argv[i] for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )

    char* StringsFromArgs[] = {argv[1], argv[2], NULL}

    //some work here

    exit(0);

}
```

Don't see a reason to use `malloc()` at all.

Comment: Absolutely. I would rather say, that there is no need to store the argv's in some other variables unless you intend to modify them which I fail to see in the OP question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like also

```
#include <assert.h>  // assert()
#include <stdlib.h>  // malloc() and free()

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int i = 0,k = 0;

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        char **StringsFromArgs = malloc((argc - 1) * sizeof(char *));

        for(i=0;i<argc-1;i++)
        {
              if(strcmp(argv[i+1],"somestring")==0)
              {
                 StringsFromArgs[k] = argv[i+1];
                 printf("Argument%d:%s\n",i+1,StringsFromArgs[k]);
                 k++;
              }
        }
    }

   free( StringsFromArgs ) ;
   return 0;
}
```